# Disable Automatic Linking of Mailing Address in WebView

Tags: android, webview, linkify

The android WebView will automatically detect a mailing address in the html and allow you to click on it to launch a map. Is there anyway to disable this without a native code change? Can I add something to the html markup or cancel a javascript event to prevent this from happening?

If I need to make this change in native code, how is that done?

EDIT:
When I say mailing address, I mean a physical street address, like:

123 Main Street
Sometown, CA 12345

Comment: Is it a mailto:address@place.com link in the html? or is it just plain text?

Comment: i think he is referring to a building address

Comment: I think Kevin is correct but the question is ambiguous, OP can you clarify?

Comment: I am referring to a physical street address. I updated the question with an example. Thanks!

Comment: I face this issue once. I used this little trick: < span >mail< /span >@sample.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try using the following meta tag in the page you're including in the WebView, if that's possible.

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />
```

Source: http://phpaul.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/writing-a-webpage-for-a-mobile-device/