# Disabling email,number detection in android WebView

Tags: cordova, android-intent, sencha-touch-2, android-webview, android-websettings

I'm developing an app with phonegap+sencha touch2+android. 
I've one panel showing various content that contains emails, some numbers in textual form. As it's a WebView when I tap on number, andorids default MailCompose Activity starts, when I tap on number Dialer Activity starts. How can I disable this from happening. Is there some config I'm missing from android side before loading url or web settings for WebView. Or something from Phonegap because when I saw log cat it shows following line -

`DroidGap.startActivityForResult(intent,-1)`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472547/disable-the-automatic-linkify-of-webview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771687/disable-automatic-linking-of-mailing-address-in-webview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188883/preventing-autolinking-of-emails-and-urls-in-an-android-webview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to add the following to the `<head>` of your HTML document.

```
<head>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="email=no" />
</head>
```

This should work on most WebKit browsers, such as Android, BlackBerry, and iOS.

Comment: I have never tried these tags, but it should also be possible for you to inject these into the HTML page in your WebView so that you don't have to change the pages in question.